# How to handle side-effects in the context of Rollup tree-shaking?

Tags: javascript, bundler, rollupjs, side-effects

[rollupjs](/questions/tagged/rollupjs) is flagging a side effect here:

```
renderer/Logger.ts (3:7) First side effect in renderer/Logger.ts is at (2:0)
1: import { Roarr } from "roarr";
2: export const Logger = Roarr.child({
   ^
3:   application: "contra-web-app"
4: });
```

This file is included by a bunch of other files.

It appears that because this file is being identified as a side-effect, rollup is unable to merge other files that depend on it (the `experimentalMinChunkSize` setting).

What can I do in this case?

Rollup documentation mentions [`@__PURE__`](https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#pure) and [`@__NO_SIDE_EFFECTS__`](https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#no-side-effects), but the documentation makes it sound like if I mark this code as `@__PURE__`, it will get removed, which is not the intent.

> That means that Rollup will tree-shake i.e. remove the call unless the return value is used in some code that is not tree-shaken.

Unless I don't understand what remove means, I don't want to remove the logger – I want the logger to continue to function.

Many other components have files similar to:

```
// Button.tsx

import { Logger } from './Logger.ts';

const logger = Logger.child({...});

export default Button = () => {};
```

Would it mean that I have to move `logger.child()` to inside `Button` component function?

Comment: Removing the logger if it is really not used sounds fine to me? But I don't think that's the issue, rather you will want to treat the instantiation of the (stateful?) logger as a side effect.

Comment: Edited the question with same information since the formatting in comments is off.

Comment: I don't see why it would be removed then, since the other files do use it.

Comment: Right, but the original problem remains – rollup identifies this as a side-effect and it prevents those component files from being merged into the same chunk. I want all those small components merged in the same file.

Comment: "*it prevents those component files from being merged into the same chunk*" - no. It prevents this module from being merged into **different** chunks. You want one logger instance, not multiple ones, right?

Comment: As stated in the docs it `remove the call unless the return value is used`, so `export const Logger = /*@__NO_SIDE_EFFECTS__*/ Roarr.child()` won't remove the `Roarr.child()` call. Unrelated but I'm curious: do you know why Rollup detects a side-effect here? Could be worth it to dig into this.